# htppd.conf or other local issue loading any php file in one specific localhost directory

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, httpd.conf

**Firefox:**

"You have chosen to open (no file name here?) which is a: application/x-httpd-php (12.6 KB) from http://localhost"

"What should Firefox do with this file? Open with () Save File [ BROWSE ]"

And if I Save File, the file names is: "ywooukMV.part" ???

**Chrome:**

Just prompts for download of file name. And the file name by default is "download"

---

I spent some time researching this, and all I could locate as a "fix" was to ensure my httpd.conf had the correct call for:

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

In addition, I am having no problem reading other php files. This is the only directory (in any directory below it as well) that prompts this download and will not load the file.

I am using WAMP server. I've tried multiple versions of Apache and PHP and the result is the same.

I have other php files and directories in the same localhost, and none of them have this same problem.

There is no .htaccess file located in the directory either which I thought might be something that could cause this with a configuration.

Is there something specific I can look for to resolve this?

I'm at a dead end.

Comment: Ok. I lost enough hair over this. My IDE ftp explorer and file tree where not showing the .htaccess file. But I re-checked in explorer and found that was the culprit. SOLVED..